# wireframe complex (expandable) grids

Tags: wireframe, mockups, balsamiq

Is it possible to wire frame a grid with expanded rows like this:

[Telerik example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/nestedviewtemplate/defaultcs.aspx)

[Balsamic](http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/110188) looks interesting but I am not sure whether it can be used for complex scenarios like the one above.

Ideally, I am looking for something free. Currently, I am using [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/), which is great but the achievable grids/tables are very basic - especially if you want to use many columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balsamiq offers 'Mockups To Go', which to my understanding allows users to combine building block mockups. An example of an expandable wire frame grid can be found here:

[Master Detail Grid - Balsamic Mockup](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/controls/Datagrid%20Master-Detail)

Comment: Link is dead :(

Answer (score 2):

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156937/balsamiq-mockups-alternative-for-building-wireframes).

More complete list of mockup tools is [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools).

And people do create such complex layouts with my own tool [MockupScreens](http://mockupscreens.com).

Comment: MockupScreens looks good. May download the trial. As it is your own tool - could you please answer the specific part of the question regarding 'expandable rows' (see telerik example) - this may save me quite a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: I have downloaded your software. It seems to be great and can be easily used. However, I could not create 'advanced tables/grids', which is a 'hard' requirement for me.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen your question in time to save you the trouble. People *mockup* those too, but with great effort I have to admit.
Tables (especially advanced tables) are in general hard to nail down with such kind of tool because mockup tool by definition has to be as simple to use as it gets. Additionally my goal was to make life easier for analysts (and me as one of "them") so it's low-fidelity. You might check Axure or another tool from the above list that can do high-fidelity mockups, too.